# What is wrong with my function that some sets of numbers worked and others don't?

Tags: c, function

I am supposed to take the users input and say if it's a valid date or not, but some dates print out it's valid or invalid then other times it just takes the input and the program ends with no output.

When user enters 15/11/11, it rearranges to 11/15/15.  If the user enters
`12/12/12`, it works normally, but `04/16/16` just doesn't give any output.

Where is the problem in my function causing this issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Declares function
int check_date(int month, int day, int year);

int main(void) {
    int day, month, year;

    //Asks user for input.
    printf("Enter a date in this format : MM/DD/YY:");


    //If user enters a wrong format it will be invalid.
    if (scanf_s("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year) == 3) {
        check_date(day, month, year);
    }
    else {
        printf("You entered a invalid date.\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

int check_date(int month, int day, int year) {

    // If user inputs a valid date this will run.
    if (month > 0 && month <= 12 && day > 0 && day <= 31 && year > 0 && year <= 99)
    {
        switch (month) {

        //If users month input is 2(febuary) this case will run.
        case 2:
            //If it is a leap year and the day 29 is entered it is invalid.
            if (year % 4 == 0) {
                if (day == 29) {
                    printf("Invalid date.");
                }
                else {
                    printf("You entered a valid date, %d/%d/%d", month, day, year);
                }
                break;
        //If user inputs 4 this case will run.
        case 4:
            //There is not 31 days in this month.
            if (day == 31) {
                printf("Invalid date.");
            }
            else {
                printf("You entered a valid date, %d/%d/%d", month, day, year);
            }
            break;

        //If user inputs 4 this case will run.
        case 6:
            //There is not 31 days in this month.
            if (day == 31) {
                printf("Invalid date.");
            }
            else {
                printf("You entered a valid date, %d/%d/%d", month, day, year);
            }
            break;

        //If user inputs 4 this case will run.
        case 9:
            //There is not 31 days in this month.
            if (day == 31) {
                printf("Invalid date.");
            }
            else {
                printf("You entered a valid date, %d/%d/%d", month, day, year);
            }
            break;
        //If user inputs 4 this case will run.
        case 11:
            //There is not 31 days in this month.
            if (day == 31) {
                printf("Invalid date.");
            }
            else {
                printf("You entered a valid date, %d/%d/%d", month, day, year);
            }
            break;
        //If user enters any other date other then the cases it is valid.
        default: 
            printf("You entered a valid date, %d/%d/%d", month, day, year);
            break;
        }
            //If user enters anything other then the correct format, this else will run.
            else {
                printf("You entered a invalid date.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which dates worked and which dates didn't? Please tell us your input values that allowed you to determine this.

Comment: Please use a [code formatter](http://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier) - you have forgotten to close one open bracket and have ended up with `switch(..) else { INVALID; }` which is syntactically valid but not what you mean - I'm voting to close as this is a typo/formatting issue.

Comment: And you call the function with `check_date(day, month, year)`, the wrong order.

Comment: @KenY-N , Thanks for the check_date.. simple mistake..

Comment: If you enter a zero for the day, the month or the year, your check date function ignores it (saying nothing).  Similarly if the values are too big for the range.

Comment: Leaving comments and code like `//If user inputs 4 this case will run.` and
`case 6:` doesn't endear you to code reviewers.  It would be better to delete the comments than to have inherently incorrect comments in the code.

Comment: You call `check_date(day, month, year);` but you define (and declare) `int check_date(int month, int day, int year)`.  Choose an order for the parameters and stick with it!  And your function doesn't return any value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, is more simple

```
/*C program to validate date (Check date is valid or not).*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int dd,mm,yy;

    printf("Enter date (DD/MM/YYYY format): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&dd,&mm,&yy);

    //check year
    if(yy>=1900 && yy<=9999)
    {
        //check month
        if(mm>=1 && mm<=12)
        {
            //check days
            if((dd>=1 && dd<=31) && (mm==1 || mm==3 || mm==5 || mm==7 || mm==8 || mm==10 || mm==12))
                printf("Date is valid.\n");
            else if((dd>=1 && dd<=30) && (mm==4 || mm==6 || mm==9 || mm==11))
                printf("Date is valid.\n");
            else if((dd>=1 && dd<=28) && (mm==2))
                printf("Date is valid.\n");
            else if(dd==29 && mm==2 && (yy%400==0 ||(yy%4==0 && yy%100!=0)))
                printf("Date is valid.\n");
            else
                printf("Day is invalid.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Month is not valid.\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Year is not valid.\n");
    }

    return 0;    
}
```